# Can this mind control work?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency

(Sister question to [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/110566/is-electricity-the-answer-to-mind-control))

### BACKGROUND:

I really like the Anime *[A Certain Scientific Railgun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Certain_Scientific_Railgun)* (it is superior to *[Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Certain_Magical_Index)*, deal with it). In it a character with the alias "[The Queen](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Shokuhou_Misaki)" has the ability to control peoples' minds. She has a character ("[Railgun](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Misaka_Mikoto)") that she hates. This character has the ability to control electricity. As such she is the only one who can resist her powers . . .

### BECAUSE

"Railgun" controls electricity. She sends a jolt into her brain and she stops the mind control in its tracks. These powers are telekinetic, so this assumes she is conscious while mind controlled, so she can activate her ability. This has no bearing on the question, but I figured I would weed out some renouncement of the premise. She can quite literally restart her brain. That brings us to

. . .

### THE QUESTION

How would such a mind control work?

#### PARAMETERS/ASSUMPTIONS:

To narrow it down:

- You can assume *mind control* to mean *body control via the brain*. No thought or memory altering allowed.
- Ignore that other psychics/telekineticists may be able to use their powers. *Railgun* is special in that she is the point of this question.
- Since the mind control is based on controlling the electrical impulses in the brain, bonus points for how this would work. Based on the sketchy science in the book I assume she somehow scans the electrical paths through the neurons and hijacks them electrically. Is that even possible (via non-telepathic, non-magic means. Does not have to be non-contact, I just need the science as a jumping off point. Has to be via the brain and via intercepting signals)?
- It has to be fast acting. In the book she points a TV remote at someone and hits a button and they are under her control (if this is relevant to the fast acting then she can do this to multiple people at a time.)
- She can control multiple people at a time so assume that is not a limit on her power.
- Preferably this would be safe. She can release her victims at will and they don't really know what happened to them.

(I tested this in the sandbox, but I figure it can graduate after a month)

Comment: It is possible to control muscles via electrodes, but remote, non-contact control is still outside of scientifically possible.

Comment: @Alexander Deleted my previous comment. I understand what you meant. Hopefully. Edited question to hopefully be better.

Comment: Down voters want to explain? The question was vetted in the sandbox but I am open to improving it.

Answer (score 4):

### No

The activity of the brain is not purely electrical, it is chemical as well.  This doesn't just mean that neurochemicals moderate the speed or ability of neurons to produce electrical signals - a given neuron will produce chemicals/electrical impulses based on the electrical and chemical signals of adjacent neurons.

Both aspects are crucial, so it's easy to *disrupt* neural activity with the application of electricity (this is part of why tasers work and is definitely what electroshock therapy is meant to do).

*Control*, on the other hand, would require manipulating both.

As has been pointed out in the comments, you could theoretically control the person like a puppet by direct electrical stimulation of their muscles, but you wouldn't be hijacking their brain, you'd be [*ASSUMING DIRECT CONTROL*](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/assuming-control).

Not only would this not be subject to any sort of brain "reset" to free you from its influence, assuming someone could do it to you, it would be *extremely* difficult to manage without some sort of technological intermediary (a computer serving as your body's brain, so to speak), since direct manipulation would require that the controller use your muscles as well as their own.  This would (obviously) get even more difficult with more people being controlled.